# How to apply :hover on SVG inner <rect> element?

Tags: css, svg, hover

I have an SVG figure and want to apply `:hover` property on one `<rect>` element inside another . But it doesn't work:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" id="svg">

    <style type="text/css"><![CDATA[
        #rec1 {
            fill:black;   // outer element
        }
        #rec2 {
            fill:white;      // inner element
            display:none;   // and element not visible
        }
        #rec1:hover #rec2 {
            display:block;   // when hover outer lets inner become visible
                             // but it doesn't work
        }
        #rec1:hover  {
            fill:red;       // strange but this hover works
        }

    ]]></style>

        <g id="g">
            <rect id="rec1" x="0" y="0" width="200" height="50" />
            <rect id="rec2" x="100" y="20" width="20" height="20" />
        </g>

</svg>
```

What is the right way to apply hover in such a case?

**UPD:** one solution found.

First it's not one `<rect>` element in another. They are siblings. And as far as such kind of styles apply `#rec1:hover #rec2` only possible with nested elements, it won't work here. So I applied style on the most outer `<g>` element:

```
#g:hover #rec2 {
    display:block;   // it works just fine
}
```

But are there any more ways to solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use:

```
#rec1:hover + #rec2 {
     display: block;                 
}
```

The `+` selector is used for selecting siblings (children of the same element -- `g` in this case), which is the case here.

Hope that helped!

Answer (score 1):

Those rectangles are not nested as far as CSS is concerned.

This style `#rec1:hover #rec2` would only apply if #rec2 was nested inside the #rec1 elements and the #rec1 element was being hovered.

Just apply the style as `#rec2:hover`

Comment: I've tried but it doesn't work either. But with your comment I found one solution. Thank you. I just forgot that such a css only works with nested elements.